# How to fetch row of max of date from a same month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table called `XX_DATE` with `columns ID, start_date, end_date, start_reading, end_reading`.

[image: Actual Data]

The last 2 rows in actual date should be fetched as single row using `max end_date` of same month as well as `max end_reading` of same month.

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: What is the logic for combining them?  Why aren't other rows combined?  How are the "reading" columns defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't as simple as it looks. But let me start with a simple answer first.

To achieve your goal, create a query and group by the actual year/month of the `end_date`, then get the `min(startdate)` and `max(end_date)` and also apply the same rules for the reading columns.

```
select min(start_date)    as start_date
,      max(end_date)      as end_date
,      min(start_reading) as start_reading
,      min(end_reading)   as end_reading
from   XX_DATE
group by trunc( end_date, 'MM')
```

One issue is that the query won't take gaps in the period into account, meaning that if there is a gap in the period of the data, it will still be showed as one record and won't indicate that there is a gap. If this is okay, you're fine, otherwise this won't work.

Another issue is by doing this, you would loose the id column and you would have to think of creating a new sequence as the id column or create an aggregated id column like `6:7` so that you can always refer to the original id's.

**ID as lowest id value**

```
select min(id)            as id
,      min(start_date)    as start_date
,      max(end_date)      as end_date
,      min(start_reading) as start_reading
,      min(end_reading)   as end_reading
from   XX_DATE
group by trunc( end_date, 'MM')
```

**ID as newly generated a id**

```
select rownum as id,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       start_reading,
       end_reading
from (
  select min(start_date)    as start_date
  ,      max(end_date)      as end_date
  ,      min(start_reading) as start_reading
  ,      min(end_reading)   as end_reading
  from   XX_DATE
  group by trunc( end_date, 'MM')
)
```

**ID as aggregated id column**

```
select listagg(id, ':') WITHIN GROUP (order by id) as id_agg
,      min(start_date)    as start_date
,      max(end_date)      as end_date
,      min(start_reading) as start_reading
,      min(end_reading)   as end_reading
from   XX_DATE
group by trunc( end_date, 'MM')
```

Comment: Thanks Giliam, you are correct but this query will group by OCT month of 2017, 2018 also. So it will not work.

Comment: Then group by year/month instead of month only. Updated my answer.

Comment: `group by trunc(end_date,'mm')` would be better than to_char

Comment: I see @SayanMalakshinov point, adding `YYYY` to the to_char solves the same issue, but I agree trunc would be the better one in most cases. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. It is solved using Giliam's approach GROUP BY TO_CHAR(C.END_READ_DTTM, 'MMYYYY').